# Using the .htaccess to redirect all of a site minus the system folder for expression engine

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect, expressionengine

I would like to redirect everything from a site `oldblog.com` to `newsite.com/blog/` with the exception of being able to access `oldblog.com/system/` and all the files within in it.

This is because of Expression engine is on this domain and the other sites need to access this to change stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^(blog|system)(/.*)?$ blog%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```